# iterate over a list of url in r

Tags: r, for-loop, web, rvest

i want to import a txt that have a list of urls and extract from each one and save that in a cvs file but i get stuck

First i import the txt no problem but when a i want to iterate over each row i just extrat from the first one

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

for(i in seq(list_url)) {
    text <- read_html(list_url$url[i]) %>%html_nodes("tr~ tr+ tr strong") %>%html_text()}
```

i just get the result from the first url in a value form , i want a dataframe of all the the extract from the urls

edit : the list_ url file is full with this urls..

http://consultas.pjn.gov.ar/cuantificacion/civil/vida_po_detalle_caso.php?numcas=_b8I7G9olKAukGNlsRE6RHSYaYPu8YLjhTEW15HEuj4.
http://consultas.pjn.gov.ar/cuantificacion/civil/vida_po_detalle_caso.php?numcas=ewwF4WmHAnOkCg8Y_XIFH705H_O5hJL9uB5hztOhrsE.
http://consultas.pjn.gov.ar/cuantificacion/civil/vida_po_detalle_caso.php?numcas=Z9BDo7ACNDbsUwTiVFTe9aKFfcLAxxnU2AtL6DCloX4.
http://consultas.pjn.gov.ar/cuantificacion/civil/vida_po_detalle_caso.php?numcas=NZPRa9SoKHVJQcZ64_4zVgcLSNKmHZ4MtorPu23MUPg.

Comment: Could you please provide the data in `list_url`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for help

Comment: You overwrite your `text` object in each pass, not sure how one would expect differently. Try `out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list_url, function(url) html_text(html_nodes(read_html(url), "..."))))`

Comment: i just put examples with the data from list_url

Comment: please provide the list as is, not links to the urls. You should use `dput(list_url)`. Paste the output of dput in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the result of the first URL you get in the `text` variable? It should be the last as with every cycle the for loop overwrites the value in `text`.

`lapply()` is perfect for this and avoids the issues that come with for-loops.

This does what you are trying to achieve:

```
text <- 
  lapply(list_url$url,
         \(x) read_html(x) %>% 
           html_nodes("tr~ tr+ tr strong") %>% 
           html_text())
```

Using `sapply()` instead you'll get a vector as a result instead of a `list`. Which might be helpful for the following steps. You might also want to look up [`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/), it provides a suite of `*apply()` like functions.

Comment: thank you so much but now i have this error.... Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Empty reply from server

Answer (score 0):

You should create an output object, then populate every element "i" of that output object with your function. As is, your code is just overwriting all the intermediate objects to the same output object.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

text<-vector('list', length=length(list_url)) #create the output object
for(i in seq(list_url)) {
    text[[i]] <- read_html(list_url$url[i]) %>%html_nodes("tr~ tr+ tr strong") %>%html_text()}
text
```

Comment: thank you but it returns only the first url

Comment: I is hard to get it right without a proper reproducible example. Maybe if you provide a sample of list_url we can help you more

Comment: yes i edit it. thank you

Comment: please provide the list with `dput(list_url)`